# Nginx proxy_pass to http or https different behavior

Tags: http, nginx, https, proxy, request

Good day! We have a nginx-based proxy with next config:

```
server {
  server_name  proxy;
  listen 80;
  underscores_in_headers on;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  bodylog;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X:Y;
  }
}
```

Backend is an application with first login page access to search after it. So the problem is:
When we tune proxy to IP address of backend (proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X:Y) we get that all requests after login in browser in start page go through nginx proxy-server and we can log them to access.log.

But if we want to use here https://address.com for the same application like that

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://address.com;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
  }
```

we got that only first load of login page goes through nginx proxy, but all other actions there (login itself, search after it, etc.) go right on domain https://address.com (not through proxy-server), so cannot be logged in nginx-proxy access.log file, but we need this!
Is there anyway to change this behavior like with proxy_pass to IP?

---

Additional info: Application deployed in kube cluster, so when I try to reach it to IP requests go to kube-service for app with type LB and then to app. When hen I try to reach it to DNS name with https request go to nginx-ingress-controller in cluster, then to kube-service for app and then to app

Answer (score 0):

I see you are working with port `80` that is http and using proxy_pass https://address.com; that is port `443`.

Maybe upgrading to https would help?
putting example here:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #begin of SSL
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
    #end of SSL
```

If your proxy server has several network interfaces, sometimes you might need to choose a particular source IP address for connecting to a proxied server or an upstream. This may be useful if a proxied server behind NGINX is configured to accept connections from particular IP networks or IP address ranges.
Try to specify the proxy_bind directive and the IP address of the necessary network interface:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://address.com;
    proxy_bind 127.0.0.11;
}
```

Comment: Already checked, remake config for proxy to listen on 443 with certs an proxy_pass. Have the same - using IP - all requests goes through proxy (even address in browser is the dns name of nginx server while login/search on portal, etc). Using `https://address.com` in proxy_pass gets first request to proxy-server goes to application, but in address string of browser address changes to `https://address.com` and all next requests in browser to app goes around proxy (((

Comment: Try to use proxy_bind, I have edited my answer with example.